# Dagger 2: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Can't build project with Dagger 2 (Android Studio 1.3).

Step 1. Add dependencies to build.gradle

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'    
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Full build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {        
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.+'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.+'

    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.jar')

}
```

Step 2.

Just add annotation `@Inject` or `@Module` to code and get compile error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.filterKeys(Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;)Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;

Any ideas?

**Update**

I'm create new project.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'   
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'    

    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.jar')    
}
```

And it compile fine. When I add to libs `guava-r07.jar` I get like compile error. I think the problem relate with `guava`.

**Solved**

1. Remove `guava-r07.jar` from libs.
2. Add to build.gradle

   compile 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1'

Comment: The current version of Guava is 18.0 and there is a release candidate 19.0-rc1. Are you sure that `Multimpas.filterKeys` is present in the jar you added? Otherwise, upgrade to the last version of guava which is 18.0

Comment: Probably present, since there are no compilation errors. In any case, thank you, I'll update guava.